# PeerJS Error when Trying to Broadcast

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I am attempting to make a broadcast function in PeerJS by listing all the peers and sending each one a message. My client code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const peer = new Peer({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 4982, path: '/', debug: 2});

      peer.on('open', function(id) {
        document.getElementById('peerId').innerHTML = id;
      });

      peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      });

      function bcast(message, id) {
        peer.listAllPeers(function(peers) {
          console.log(peers);

          // remove self from peer list
          peers.splice(peers.indexOf(id), 1);

          if (peers.length > 0) {
            peers.forEach(function(e, i) {
              let conn = peer.connect(e);
              conn.on('open', function() {
                conn.send(message);
              });
            });
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Peer ID: <p id="peerId"></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="bcast('hello', id)">Broadcast Hello Message</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

My signaling server code is below:

```
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
var server = PeerServer({port: 4982, path: '/', allow_discovery: true});
```

To test it, I start the server and open two browser tabs, tab 1 and tab 2. Then, I click the Broadcast Hello Message button in tab 1. I expect 'hello' to be logged in tab 2, instead get this error:

```
PeerJS:  WARNING Offer received for existing Connection ID: dc_eyxb5yz4k4eonyb4d0f3whfr
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate
```

Strangely, without reloading anything, if I click the broadcast button in tab 2 **it logs it in tab 1**. I am new to WebRTC so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ever figure it out? I'm seeing the same thing.